# C++ cocos2d-x pointer

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I've just used **cocos2d-x** for creating some games. When I read the **HelloWorld.cpp**, I saw this line

```
 Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
```

That's strange for me. How does it work? A method named **creatScene** that takes no parameters and returns a pointer to a **Scene** ?

Comment: If you want to know how it works / what it does just look into the createScene method. After all cocos2d is open source. If you don't understand the code inside it then that's a more interesting/helpful question to ask. Your question is receiving downvotes probably because the question shows a lack of effort.

Answer (score -1):

In different libraries, there are different methods to initialize library or some part of that. So, in this case, it maybe create a new context inside library and return it without any argument.
 It maybe needs no arguments (use defaults) it this step of get them from somewhere else like configuration file. And note that this is convenient to use this type of initializing. Like this:

```
rc = redis.Redis() #uses default values for server address
```

Answer (score -1):

It is really an easy question even it cannot be called as question when you check the source code.

In cocos2d-x, CCScene always create this way.

```
1. create a Layer, which coded by yourself with a lot of other widgets.
2. create a Scene
3. add the layer to the scene
4. return the scene you create.
```